# Unable to set Hibernate flush mode to MANUAL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flush

We would like to set the flush mode of Hibernate to `MANUAL`.

We use the spring property: `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode`. This property works fine for `COMMIT`, `ALWAYS` and `AUTO`. `MANUAL` is also accepted and correctly parsed (as we saw during code debugging).

Sadly when we check the flush mode with

```
 ((org.hibernate.Session) entityManager).getHibernateFlushMode()
```

we see that first three options work fine but if we set to `MANUAL` the flush mode in the session is `AUTO`.

Is this a bug or a feature and how can we get around it?

Spring Boot version: 2.6.4
Hibernate version: 5.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation showed that a method annotated with `@Transactional` changes flush mode from `MANUAL` to `AUTO`.
We changed to `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` (which was in our case even more correct) and solved the problem.